# How to match a string with quantifiers as literals?

Tags: regex, scala

Let say I have a string: `"....O RLY?.....WTF?"`

And I want to match it with a pattern:

```
val pattern = "BOTH SAEM|O RLY?|YA RLY|NO WAI|OIC|WTF?|OMG|GTFO|OMGWTF".r
```

But it never captures the `?` in my string. So I change it to:

```
val pattern = "BOTH SAEM|O RLY\?|YA RLY|NO WAI|OIC|WTF\?|OMG|GTFO|OMGWTF".r
```

This time it raises `invalid escape character` error.

I'm a newbie in Regex and can't find a solution for this. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the question mark twice:

```
val pattern = "BOTH SAEM|O RLY\\?|YA RLY|NO WAI|OIC|WTF\\?|OMG|GTFO|OMGWTF".r
```

The explanation here is that you want to feed `\?` into the regex engine, to tell it to treat the question mark as a literal.  But you need to escape the backslash itself, so that Scala won't think you're trying to escape the question mark in the Scala code.

Answer (score 0):

By twice escaping the question mark you avoid this error, but it does not find your alternative `O RLY?` and `WTF?`.
You better use `O RLY[?]` and `WTF[?]` in your pattern to match the literal character `?`.

To test this I used  [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

PS: in the case you want to process the results use () in your pattern like this 
`(O RLY[?])`